# Video tearing sorted now Low cube performance

Tags: nvidia, compiz, tearing, cube

I've just sorted out the tearing in videos on my PC following this guide:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1390284

However before this i had a wonderfully performing cube, Nice smooth and no/very little tearing (at least only around the sides) Now however the cube feels slow when rotating and i get some sort of tearing (white lines) underneath my gnome panel when 'landing' on a desktop
Any ideas how i can return to the previous performance of the cube without turning sync to VBlank off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original questioner's comment on nate8nate's answer confirms that Ubuntu "10.10 with the new 260 Nvidia graphics driver" fixes the problems.